# Change stacking order of Vertical Menu built with Bootstrap 3 in Wordpress sidebar

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now trying various solutions found on-line but nothing is working. I am trying to create my first Bootstrap 3 site with WordPress. I am wanting to create a vertical menu which should be responsive. The only way I can think how is to put it in the sidebar? It works fine except of course if the window resize the menu is jumping to the bottom where I need it to go to the top. I'm working locally so I don't have a link to post but I'm hoping someone could give me some advice please?

This is the script that was suppose to work according to a tutorial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $html = $('#menu-bar');

    $window.resize(function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 768) {
           return $html.removeClass('nav-stacked');
        }
        $html.addClass('nav-stacked');
    }).trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**Update:**

I've come closer to a solution. It works with the below script, except when I resize the window back to full width the menu display as a full width menu pushing everything else on the page down.

Could that be a CSS problem?

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    if ($(window).width() <= 768){ 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#sidebar-nav').insertAfter('#myJumbotron'); 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

Someone suggested that it could be a JS problem? Is there anyone that know more?

The solution to this for future users:

```
 $(function(){
 // initial size adjustments
  resizeMe();
 // Resized window!
  $(window).on("resize",function(){
    resizeMe();
   });
 });

 function resizeMe(){
  if ($(window).width() <= 768){  
   $('#sidebar-nav').insertAfter('#myJumbotron');
 }else{
   $("#sidebarBG").prepend($("#sidebar-nav"));
  }
 };
```

Comment: I've come closer to a solution. It works with the below script, except when I resize the window back to full width the menu display as a full width menu pushing everything else on the page down. Could that be a CSS problem? I now have a link to the test site:

http://www.hlsmentors.angelicdesign.co.uk/

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function(){
if ($(window).width() <= 768){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sidebar-nav').insertAfter('#myJumbotron');
});
}
});
</script>
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyone that could possible look at this. I am not any closer to a solution. When the screen resizes or I change the tablet from portrait to landscape the navigation menu stretches over the screen instead of jumping to the sidebar. Thank you!

Comment: The solution to this for future users:                                                      $(function(){
  // initial size adjustments
  resizeMe();
  // Resized window!
  $(window).on("resize",function(){
    resizeMe();
  });
});

function resizeMe(){
  if ($(window).width() <= 768){  
    $('#sidebar-nav').insertAfter('#myJumbotron');
  }else{
    $("#sidebarBG").prepend($("#sidebar-nav"));
  }
};